# QgsAttributeForm disappears using it in a QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'im trying to make appear a QgsAttributeForm of one feature in my QGIS plugin, but the form disappears just after it appears.
Here is my code (used with QGIS 3.22):

```
class TestAttForm:
    
    # Initialization
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.project = QgsProject.instance()
        
        # Initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    
            
    # Initialisation of the menu and the toolbar
    def initGui(self):
        
        # Add specific toolbar
        self.sgm_tb = self.iface.addToolBar("Test")
        self.sgm_tb.setObjectName("Test")

        
        # Create actions
        self.action_test = QAction(
            QIcon(r":test"), "Test QgsAttributeForm", self.iface.mainWindow())
            
        # Add actions to the toolbar
        self.sgm_tb.addActions([self.action_test])
        
        # Manage signals
        self.action_test.triggered.connect(self.test)

        
    # Unload actions
    def unload(self) :
        if self.sgm_tb != None:
            self.iface.mainWindow().removeToolBar(self.sgm_tb)        
        
    def test(self):
        layer = self.canvas.currentLayer()
        att_form = QgsAttributeForm(layer, list(layer.getFeatures())[0])
        att_form.setMode(QgsAttributeEditorContext.SingleEditMode)
        att_form.show()
```

When I try to use the same code (code of test function) directly in the python console, it works well.
What is the problem in my plugin code ? Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the plugin class you need to store the `QgsAttributeForm` object as an instance variable instead of using a local variable. This is needed because as soon as the method finishes its execution, local variables will be destroyed by Pythons Garbage Collector. Therefore the widget is destroyed and it disappears immediately.

Using the code of your test function in QGIS console works, because all variables are then kept in a global scope where they are not affected by garbage collection.

So in conclusion, all you need to do is replace your test function with the following snippet:

```py
def test(self):
    layer = self.canvas.currentLayer()
    self.att_form = QgsAttributeForm(layer, list(layer.getFeatures())[0])
    self.att_form.setMode(QgsAttributeEditorContext.SingleEditMode)
    self.att_form.show()
```

Comment: It works fine. Thank you for the explanation.